# Moving android studio project from mac to windows

Tags: java, ios, windows, android-studio

I just got an android studio project folder from a mac laptop and am currently trying to open it in windows android studio. I'm not quite sure but it doesn't seem to be detecting any of the files. I'm not really familiar with android studio at this point any suggestions on how to build this project in windows would be much appreciated.

all the best

Comment: How did you export the project, or get the files from the Mac to the Windows machine?

Comment: As far as I know my buddy just grabbed the project folder from the mac and drag and dropped onto my jump drive.

Comment: Make sure that the folder you have includes the needed .project and .classpath files, otherwise Android Studio most likely won't recognize your files as an existing project

Comment: Do you happen to know where in the mac android studio project folder the source code is located? what he gave me looks much different than what the windows android studio sets up.